# Combine route path from the controller in a method ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an AppointmentController with a Route attribute and an HTTPGet method inside of it

```cs
[ApiController, Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AppointmentController : ControllerBase 
{

    [HttpGet("/user/{userId:guid}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse<IEnumerable<Appointment>>>> GetUserAppointments([FromRoute] Guid userId) {}

}
```

I want the route to be : "/api/appointment/user/:userId"

Instead I get "/user/:userId" in the Swagger UI

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the forward slash `/` before your route `"user/{userId:guid}"`

```cs
[ApiController, Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AppointmentController : ControllerBase 
{

    [HttpGet("user/{userId:guid}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse<IEnumerable<Appointment>>>> GetUserAppointments([FromRoute] Guid userId) {}

}
```